# Flutter w/ MobX: Snackbar Won't Show Up When Exception Occured

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to fetch an API from internet using http package and i'm using MobX for state management. The problem i'm having is that when an exception occured in fetching the data from internet is that the the snackbar won't pop up displaying the error message although there is no unhandled exception error printed in the console. This is the code related to the problem.

The homepage

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  QuestionStore _store;
  List<ReactionDisposer> _reactionDisposer;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    _store ??= Provider.of<QuestionStore>(context);
    _reactionDisposer ??= <ReactionDisposer>[
      reaction(
        // Checking the error message, if error message is not null
        // show snackbar showing the error message
        //TODO: Fix snackbar won't show up
        (_) => _store.errorMessage,
        (String message) {
          _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(
            SnackBar(
              content: Text(message),
            ),
          );
        },
      )
    ];
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _reactionDisposer.forEach((reaction) => reaction());
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ScreenConfig().init(context);

    return Scaffold(
      body: Observer(
        builder: (_) {
          switch (_store.state) {
            case StoreState.loading:
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

            case StoreState.initial:
              return UserInput();

            case StoreState.loaded:
              return CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  CustomSliverAppBar(question: _store.questionsData),
                  CustomSliverList(question: _store.questionsData),
                ],
              );

              break;
          }

          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The state management

```
part 'question_store.g.dart';

class QuestionStore = _QuestionStore with _$QuestionStore;

enum StoreState {initial, loading, loaded}

abstract class _QuestionStore with Store {
  final QuestionsService questionsService = QuestionsService();

  @observable
  ObservableFuture<CoreData> questionFuture;

  @observable
  CoreData questionsData;

  @observable
  String errorMessage;

  @computed
  StoreState get state {
    if (questionFuture == null ||
        questionFuture.status == FutureStatus.rejected) {
      return StoreState.initial;
    }
    return questionFuture.status == FutureStatus.pending
        ? StoreState.loading
        : StoreState.loaded;
  }
  @action
  Future fetchQuestionData(String value) async{
    try{
      errorMessage = null;
      questionFuture = ObservableFuture(
        questionsService.fetchQuestion(value).then((value) => value));
      questionsData = await questionFuture;
    // If there is an error, give errorMessage a String value
    // of the error
    } on HttpException {
      errorMessage = "Error 404: Data Not Found";
    } on SocketException{
      errorMessage = "Internet Not Found";
    } on FormatException {
      errorMessage = "Not valid url";
    }
  }
}
```

The file for parsing JSON file

```
class QuestionsService {
  Future<CoreData> fetchQuestion(String url) async {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    ConnectivityResult connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
      CoreData parsedQuestions = CoreData.fromJson(jsonResponse);

      return parsedQuestions;

    } else if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      throw SocketException("Internet connection not found");

    } else if (response.statusCode == 404) {
      throw HttpException("Error 404");
      
    } else {
      throw FormatException();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this. The problem is not in the MobX file or the file for parsing the JSON data. It's in the home page file. I forgot to add the key in the scaffold widget

```
return Scaffold(
  key: _scaffoldKey // Add the key
  body: //...
```

Now the snackbar should appear if there is an error.